# Plugin Warning Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

Im trying to connect with facebook and set `build.setting` like:

```
settings = 
{
    ...
    plugins =
    {
        ["facebook"] = --"plugin.facebook.v4"
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
        },
    },
    ... 
    iphone =
    {
        plist =
        {

            CFBundleURLTypes =
            {
                { CFBundleURLSchemes = { "fbxxxxx68949xxxxx", } }
            },
            FacebookAppID = "xxxxx68949xxxxx",
            ...
         }
    }
}
```

__

But i'm getting this warning...

[image]

I have no idea what's causing this, I have checked my firewall for possible blockage  but it's turned off. Even the sample inside `/Applications/CoronaSDK-2873/SampleCode/Networking` pops the same warning..

How do I make this work?

By the way my account is not enterprise yet, is that a factor?

> I have no idea what just happen, I opened the project now (after 15hrs) and it's working now. I didn't do anything, the plugins has been downloaded as expected. My thoughts though is, that warning above was caused by slow internet connection. This confuses me a lot, I even tried restarting my pc, disconnect and reconnect both Lan and wifi but nothing works and NOW out of nowhere boom, working.

**Edit:**

The warning came back after I `force quit` corona simulator, i also encounter this errors during build(for device testing):

```
May 03 03:56:38.891 ERROR: Builder failed: sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
May 03 03:56:38.898 BUILD ERROR: There was a problem linking the app.

                    Check the console for more information.
May 03 03:56:38.935 iOS build failed (12)
May 03 03:56:39.183 ERROR: Build Failed: There was a problem linking the app.

                    Check the console for more information.
```

---

Every time I have the plugins, but if i remove the plugins... it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to use the Facebook plugin, but here is my guess.

The Facebook plugin is no longer used with Corona SDK, except for legacy code. On Corona's Facebook plugin documentation, it states:

> Starting with daily build 2015.2747, we've removed the Corona
>   Simulator plugin stub for this plugin from Corona SDK. This is to
>   encourage upgrading to the Facebook-v4 plugin.

They are now using facebook-v4, which has a different setup and can be found on its documentation page here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/facebook-v4/index.html

You are using an out-dated plugin that is no longer supported for newer builds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you; That's in beta mode, but i also tried that, as you can see i commented the **plugin.facebook.v4**, and also we managed to try our code from my colleagues iMac and it works without that plugin warning.

Comment: Does the app work even with the error messages when you "Continue Anyway"? I was looking up some similar issues for you, and I came across a few posts saying that a warning usually appears due to connection issues (I assume when launching Corona), but works after the app is loaded (I assume when Facebook API is connected). So, if that is the case, it should solve itself during run-time, and ignoring the warning is okay.

Comment: No, the app doesn't build and pops and error, something like linking error, i'll edit my question later and add that..

Comment: Does the build(for device testing) work when you try building the "Hello World" example? It could be an issue with the Corona build you are using not being compatible with your version of XCode. If you continue to have build errors, your best bet is to post your issue on https://forums.coronalabs.com/ Their moderators will likely respond to your issue more effectively.

Comment: Yes, when i remove the *plugins* in build setting everything works fine, build and everything..